# IntelliJ, analyzing Scala code

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, static-analysis

When i am using `IntelliJ` to analyze (`Analyze->Inspect code`) my `Java` code, which happens to have an unused method, they are flagged. This same behavior does not seem to be happening with `Scala`.

For instance, `IntelliJ` finds no issues with

```
   object Main {

       def main(args: Array[String]) {
       }

       private def max(a: Int, b: Int) = {   // <---- unused
         if (a > b) a else b
       }
    }
```

[image]

Can i enable this (and other) checks somehow? What am i missing please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the Scala plugin for IDEA doesn't have an inspection for unused methods (even private ones).

For Java, IDEA has "Unused declaration":

> This inspection reports classes, methods or fields in the specified inspection scope that are not used or not reachable from entry points.

Unfortunately the only related inspection for Scala is "Unused Symbol."

The only related issue I could find is [SCL-3121](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-3121). You could add a feature request on the issue tracker for unused method highlighting.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's appropriate that IntelliJ does not set it as unused because the `max` method is defined as a public method.

Comment: Checked with my IntelliJ IDEA 12.0 and actually

Comment: Indeed they're not flagged. Instead of that, you can see the method name paled out though that might not meet your expectation.

Comment: Would be nice to have the ability to check even for unused public methods